# Wiring a remote control switch?

Tags: wiring, switch

I recently bought a Chinese remote control switch using radio frequency, it's great but has a problem (note I am a newbie), I have a light switch receiving a hot wire only and giving it to the light bulb, the remote control switch has a live and neutral wiring and whenever I try connecting only live wires the remote won't work, what makes it a problem is that I believe the neutral wires are joined inside the wall or hidden in some way.
So my question is Can I wire the remote control switch without the neutral wires, note that I tried joining the neutral wires together of course it did not work so the circuit is opened.

link to the remote control switch

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/R1B1-1-Way-Port-200V-240V-Light-Digital-Wireless-Wall-Remote-Control-Switch/32266711710.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some electronic switches power themselves by running a trickle current through the light, but that doesn't work well with modern efficient bulbs.

Others, such as the one you got, require a neutral connection -- which is standard in new construction but isn't present in many older houses.

Sorry, but unless you run a neutral to that box you can't use this switch there.

Comment: Hi it's been a long time but I actually wired it to the lamp itself instead of the power outlet